# Write in table format c

Tags: c

I'm tryng to print infro from linked list and i cant get it to line up like that: [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k46JN.png)

what do I write in the printf so it will work with the spaces? here the code (p and frame are structs, just to be more clear)

```
FrameNode* p = head;
    printf("                Name            Duration        Path");

    while (p->next)
    {
        printf("%s %d %s\n", p->frame->name, p->frame->duration, p->frame->path);
        p = p->next;
    }
```

and pls try something simple im new

Comment: Question asking for debugging help must provide a [complete minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also provide the exact input, expected result and actual result. Finally please do not post text as an image - paste it directly as formatted text into the quesiton.

Comment: `printf("%-20s", p->frame->name)` will left-align in a field width of 20 with space padding. Please see [format specifications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/format-specification-syntax-printf-and-wprintf-functions?view=msvc-160).

Comment: You can specify a field width as part of each format specifier: `printf( "%-*s%-*s%-*s\n", name_width, "Name", duration_width, "Duration", path_width, "Path" );` for the header and `printf( "%-*s%*d%-*s\n", name_width, p->frame->name, duration_width, p->frame->duration, path_width, p->frame->path );` for each row of data.  The `-` in the format specifier will left-align that field.